# prevent oracle before update trigger failure to stop updating table

Tags: sql, oracle

if you create before update trigger on a table and this trigger failed due to any reason the user can not update the table until you fix or remove the trigger.so is there any way to prevent this? i mean if you made a mistake on writing the trigger and wanted the update to continue

Comment: You could add an EXCEPTION block to catch all exceptions and silently ignore them.  This is a nice landmine for future developers who are wondering why the update trigger isn't doing whatever it's meant to be doing.  See: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/WHEN_OTHERS

Comment: Find the mistake in the trigger and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you are potentially creating an invalid trigger, then you should create the trigger in a disabled state. Then you can confirm that it compiles correctly before enabling it.

It doesn't help with runtime errors.

If you are replacing an existing trigger, the new code will still replace the old and will still be disabled. If you are relying on the trigger code to set a mandatory value then that will result in a runtime error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TRIG
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
DISABLED
BEGIN
  :NEW.TEST_KEY := TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Comment: i mean if the trigger was valid on the time i create it and running ok and due to other circumstances on the database like deleting tables or adding constraints to the relying tables which makes the trigger invalid and this made other users unable to update the table until you fix the trigger. so is there any way to write before update trigger on a table and if the trigger failed you can update the table